# Why property changed value is null after changing the property value?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

Can anyone tell me why `PropertyChanged` value comes null in `INotifyPropertyChanged`. I have a property and I change its value, but when it enters in `NotifyPropertyChanged` method the value of PropertyChanged is null. Following is my code :

```
  public class WorkOrder : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {

   public string _orderDays="0 Days";

    public string OrderDays 
    { 
        get { return _orderDays; }
        set
        {
            if (_orderDays == value)
                return;
            _orderDays = value;

            NotifyPropertyChanged("OrderDays");
        }  
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    // This method is called by the Set accessor of each property.
    // The CallerMemberName attribute that is applied to the optional propertyName
    // parameter causes the property name of the caller to be substituted as an argument.
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]String propertyName =null )
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

---

this is the xaml where I bind the value

```
<Label x:Name="lblTicketDate" Text="{Binding OrderDays}" 
    Grid.Row="1" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
    VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"  />
```

Comment: Are you binding this property on the XAML?

Comment: Yes, On label. But change is not reflecting on xaml

Comment: It sounds like the problem may well be in the XAML then - but we can't see that...

Comment: <Label x:Name="lblTicketDate" Text="{Binding OrderDays}" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" FontFamily="Roboto Light" TextColor="#ffffff" FontSize="9.67" /> this is the xaml where I bind the value

Comment: are you setting the BindingContext?

Comment: Yes from code behind

Answer (score 2):

> but when it enters in NotifyPropertyChangd method the value of PropertyChanged is null

That just means that nothing has subscribed to the event yet. Beyond events, a delegate instances refers to one or more actions to execute when the delegate is invoked - a null reference is used to represent "0 actions".

If you use:

```
var order = new WorkOrder();
// Or whatever's useful instead of Console.WriteLine
order.PropertyChanged += (sender, args) => Console.WriteLine(e.PropertyName);
order.OrderDays = "Different";
```

then you'll see the event being raised.

Comment: I fired the PropertyChanged event. Now PropertyChanged value is not null and its working . But the change value is not reflecting on xaml.

Comment: @anand - can you please show how you are setting the BindingContext of the page, when you are triggering the update and I assume your binding in Xaml is Text="{Binding OrderDays}" if you are binding to a Label.

Comment: Yes Adam, <Label x:Name="lblTicketDate" Text="{Binding OrderDays}" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" FontFamily="Roboto Light" TextColor="#ffffff" FontSize="9.67" /> this is the control that binds the value.

Comment: @anand: Please put the XAML into the question instead of as a comment.